identification strategy soccer match
I have data on what minute a player was given a yellow card in a soccer match. I also know how long a particular player was on the pitch (i.e. if he was on the pitch from the start or substituted). I also know what the temperature was at the time of the match. I would like to investigate whether higher temperature has an effect on aggressive behaviour of players.
Of course, I can examine the relationship between the number of cards in a match and the temperature: $yellow\_cards \sim beta_{0} + beta_{1} \cdot temperature$
But I would like to see if this relationship is stronger late in the game, when players should be more heat exhausted and irritated. And also to see if the freshly substituted players are not affected by this relationship.
What regression specification should I use to examine this?

I would start with some plots.

@user2974951 do you mean to separately check if $yellow_cards \sim beta_{0} + beta_{1} \cdot temperature$ holds for players that are 20 minutes on the pitch, 40 minutes or 80+ minutes on the pitch?

You describe a count regression model.  These are usually fit using a Generalized Linear Model.

Start by creating a new variable for when a YC was given, which is "time since player was on pitch" (instead of time of game). Then just add 1 more predictor to your model (${\beta_2}.time-on-pitch$), and possibly an interaction term (${\beta_3}.temperature.time-on-pitch$). The interaction term will tell you exactly what you wanted. See e.g. https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/157/.  Still good old multiple linear regression (think of the interaction term as a new predictor).

@jginestet I understand the independent variables you are describing. But then at what level should the dependent variable be, i.e. yellow cards? The number of cards awarded in each minute of the game? That would be too many zero observations

Good question; for the hypothesis you are testing, it should be a count of YC's awarded. For any YC awarded in the sample, it would be the # of YC's awarded after the same time-on-pitch, at the same temperature. (for minutes of games when no card was ever awarded, you have no observations, so you do not include them). YOu will not have any 0's, but you may still have very low counts (1's and 2'); so you may need to segment the data (e.g. increments of 5 minutes, increments of 5 degrees F).
